# VS 2017 Store 'Create App Packages' Disabled

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2017

I've built a hybrid app (Cordova) in Visual Studio 2017, which builds and runs on my local Windows 10 machine without any issues.

So now I'm ready to generate the .appxupload files etc. the trouble is I cannot create the app packages because the option is disabled in Visual Studio.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Things I've already tried:

- Selecting the solution in Visual Studio before clicking on **Project -> Store**.
- I have a developer licence and the PC has the developer options (or whatever it's called) enabled.
- Rebuilt and cleaned the app several times.
- Updated Visual Studio 2017 to the latest version (even tried uninstalling/reinstalling).

Something a bit odd, when I click on **Upload App Packages...** nothing happens.

Clicking **Open Developer Account...** or **Acquire Developer Licence...** opens a Chrome for me to login and I can see my Microsoft Developer Dashboard.

**Reserve App Name...** likewise opens the Microsoft Developer Dashboard in Chrome for me to reserve an app name.  Which I've done.

I've created other apps from this pc and that option has been available before. Now when I open them and click on the **Project -> Store** I see the same greyed out options.

Can anyone help?  I'm hoping it's something simple I've missed.

Thanks

Comment: This is still an issue. I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Community on a different computer and I'm still facing the same problem. So annoying, how can I create the packages to upload to the Microsoft store :(

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to get a workaround? Otherwise we have to build with the `makeAppx` Tool https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/387791/no-store-menu-item-with-1592.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue in cordova projects, with Visual Studio Professional 2017 version `15.9.9` and i fixed it following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017

I uninstalled all versions of the Visual Studio 2017 and then installed an earlier release of VS.

According to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/387791/no-store-menu-item-with-1592.html i took version `15.8.9` and it's working again to create app packages.

I'll update this post, as soon as I recognice, that this problem is fixed in newer VS versions.

Comment: That's got it! I used those links, uninstalled the version I had (latest version) and had to roll back to `15.6.7`. Those options are now back! Has taken far, far, too long to solve that issue. Not thanks to Microsoft!

Answer (score 5):

This submenu is only clickable if you have selected, in the "Solutions Explorer" panel, your project (under your "Solution").

Comment: I've tried selecting the solution and the project but the 'Create App Packages' is grey out.

Comment: +1 because I had to click between the solution and project to get the open to activate. No re-install needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are still not a microsoft developer, click Project > Publish > Open developer account...Option, it will pop a browser's tag, completed this authentication, and then restart your visual studio project, Project > Publish > Create App Packages... option is activation!